# How to get group total inside a row in a rdl report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, olap-cube, rdl

How do I get the total of the group inside a row item?
I have tried `Fields!Sales.Value/SUM(Fields!Sales.Value)` but it returns 1 instead of the `row_amount/group_total` the report returns `row_amount/row_amount`

PS: Data comes from a SSAS cube. I made [picture bellow[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH1Gd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH1Gd.png) to summarize what I wanna do
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially just compare the values by the `ReportItems`.  That is, you can specify a name for the `sales` textbox and for the `totalsales` textbox and do the comparison using those values. The following expression would likely work as intended.

```
= (ReportItems!SalesTextbox.Value / ReportItems!SalesTotalTextbox.Value) * 100.0
```

The other thing to consider with this is that if your result is 1, you may be dealing with integer division from your data.  Make sure the data being returned is coming in with a `double` or `decimal` datatype, not an `integer`.  It may work as you have it currently if you get the datatype corrected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also had to handle divide by zero case like this `= IIF( ReportItems!SalesTotalTextbox.Value=0, 0, (ReportItems!SalesTextbox.Value / ReportItems!SalesTotalTextbox.Value) * 100.0)`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to handle "divide by Zero' errors.  Using an "=IIf (denominator = 0, 0, numerator/denominator) doesn't work since an "IIf" function evaluates both the "then" and the "else" and will still return an error.  We use a bit of custom code that I found on SO (I wish I could remember where it came from so I could give credit where it's due).

```
Public Function HandleDivideByZero(ByVal numerator As Decimal, denominator As Decimal) As Decimal
        If denominator = 0 Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return numerator / denominator
        End If
End Function
```